# I'm getting a "You can't use Gon public methods for storing data" error - Using Gon Gem and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When I start my application I get the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
F, [2015-08-11T13:32:09.513613 #10107] FATAL -- : 
RuntimeError (You can't use Gon public methods for storing data):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:228:in `set_gon'
lib/middleware/security.rb:11:in `call'
```

Line 228 is mentioned in that error. Here is what line 227 to line 237 looks like:

```
if current_user
  gon.current_user = { sn: current_user.sn }
  gon.accounts = current_user.accounts.inject({}) do |memo, account|
    memo[account.currency] = {
      currency: account.currency,
      balance: account.balance,
      locked: account.locked
    } if account.currency_obj.try(:visible)
    memo
  end
end
```

And here is what the whole method looks like:

```
def set_gon
gon.env = Rails.env
gon.local = I18n.locale
gon.market = current_market.attributes
gon.ticker = current_market.ticker
gon.markets = Market.to_hash

gon.pusher = {
  key:       ENV['PUSHER_KEY'],
  wsHost:    ENV['PUSHER_HOST']      || 'ws.pusherapp.com',
  wsPort:    ENV['PUSHER_WS_PORT']   || '80',
  wssPort:   ENV['PUSHER_WSS_PORT']  || '443',
  encrypted: ENV['PUSHER_ENCRYPTED'] == 'true'
}

gon.clipboard = {
  :click => I18n.t('actions.clipboard.click'),
  :done => I18n.t('actions.clipboard.done')
}

gon.i18n = {
  brand: I18n.t('gon.brand'),
  ask: I18n.t('gon.ask'),
  bid: I18n.t('gon.bid'),
  cancel: I18n.t('actions.cancel'),
  latest_trade: I18n.t('private.markets.order_book.latest_trade'),
  switch: {
    notification: I18n.t('private.markets.settings.notification'),
    sound: I18n.t('private.markets.settings.sound')
  },
  notification: {
    title: I18n.t('gon.notification.title'),
    enabled: I18n.t('gon.notification.enabled'),
    new_trade: I18n.t('gon.notification.new_trade')
  },
  time: {
    minute: I18n.t('chart.minute'),
    hour: I18n.t('chart.hour'),
    day: I18n.t('chart.day'),
    week: I18n.t('chart.week'),
    month: I18n.t('chart.month'),
    year: I18n.t('chart.year')
  },
  chart: {
    price: I18n.t('chart.price'),
    volume: I18n.t('chart.volume'),
    open: I18n.t('chart.open'),
    high: I18n.t('chart.high'),
    low: I18n.t('chart.low'),
    close: I18n.t('chart.close'),
    candlestick: I18n.t('chart.candlestick'),
    line: I18n.t('chart.line'),
    zoom: I18n.t('chart.zoom'),
    depth: I18n.t('chart.depth'),
    depth_title: I18n.t('chart.depth_title')
  },
  place_order: {
    confirm_submit: I18n.t('private.markets.show.confirm'),
    confirm_cancel: I18n.t('private.markets.show.cancel_confirm'),
    price: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.price'),
    volume: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.amount'),
    sum: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.total'),
    price_high: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.price_high'),
    price_low: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.price_low'),
    full_bid: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.full_bid'),
    full_ask: I18n.t('private.markets.place_order.full_ask')
  },
  trade_state: {
    new: I18n.t('private.markets.trade_state.new'),
    partial: I18n.t('private.markets.trade_state.partial')
  }
}

gon.currencies = Currency.all.inject({}) do |memo, currency|
  memo[currency.code] = {
    code: currency[:code],
    symbol: currency[:symbol],
    isCoin: currency[:coin]
  }
  memo
end
gon.fiat_currency = Currency.first.code

gon.tickers = {}
Market.all.each do |market|
  gon.tickers[market.id] = market.unit_info.merge(Global[market.id].ticker)
end

if current_user
  gon.current_user = { sn: current_user.sn }
  gon.accounts = current_user.accounts.inject({}) do |memo, account|
    memo[account.currency] = {
      currency: account.currency,
      balance: account.balance,
      locked: account.locked
    } if account.currency_obj.try(:visible)
    memo
  end
end
end
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when my code looked like this:

```
gon.push = ({
  article_id: @article.id
  })
```

and when I removed '=' all worked.

```
gon.push({
  article_id: @article.id
  })
```